# How can I find the prime numbers between 1 to the given number, only by using the loop(ie. without any short cuts) in "Ruby"?

Tags: ruby, loops, primes

Kindly help me to find the prime numbers within the given number(ie: 1..n) without using any short cuts. use only the loops in Ruby

```
puts "Enter the number to find the prime number within the number: "
n = gets.chomp.to_i
num = []
prime = [2]
not_prime = []

for i in 2..n 
   num.push i 
end 

print "We are going to seperate the prime numbers and non prime numbers from the elements present in this array: #{num}"
puts "\n\n"

for i in num 
  (2..i-1).each do |x|
    if i % x == 0
      not_prime.push i
      # break 
    else 
    prime.push i
      # break
  end 
  end 
end 
print "The prime numbers are: #{prime}" 
puts "\n"
print "The non-prime numbers are: #{not_prime}"
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). The algorithm is a bit dated but still works ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does feel a lot like a school project/task rather than anything meaningful.  There are libraries built into Ruby that you can use for high performance Prime calculations

```
puts "Enter the maximum number of the range in which to find the prime numbers: "
last = gets.chomp.to_i
prime = [2]
all_numbers = (2..last).to_a

print "We are going to separate the prime numbers and non prime numbers from the elements present in this array: #{all_numbers}\n\n"

all_numbers.each do |i|
  prime.push i unless prime.any? { |x| i % x == 0 }
end

print "The prime numbers are: #{prime}\n\n" 
print "The non-prime numbers are: #{all_numbers - prime}\n"
```